# How can I print two counter side by side in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, printing

I have a function like this.I need to print two dictionaries side by side in python.

```
def kelime_sayma(metin):
    kelimeler = metin.split()
    kelime_sayi = Counter(kelimeler)

    for i,value in kelime_sayi.most_common():
        print('{}    {}'.format(i, value))
    for j,value in sorted(kelime_sayi.items()):
        print('{}    {}'.format(j, value))
```

Comment: Are you using `collections.Counter` or is it something else? Can you show us the content of the `metin` arg?

Comment: What is the expected input for `metin`?

Comment: What is your expected output? What do you mean side by side?

Comment: Yes I am using collections.Counter @EnriqueBermúdez

Comment: metin is a text that getting from user. I need a program that prints the number of times words in a text are used. @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: can you show an example of how metin might look like?

Comment: If I use this function , dictionaries are printed one by one but I need to print side by side. @CumminUp07

Comment: just have words and space. @DeveshKumarSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```py
>>> a
['c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a']
>>> b=Counter(a)
>>> b
Counter({'a': 11, 'b': 10, 'c': 9})
>>> for i,j in zip(b.most_common(), b.items()):
...     print('{} {} {} {}'.format(i[0], i[1], j[0], j[1]))
```

---

**Output**:

```
a 11 c 9
b 10 a 11
c 9 b 10
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**:  print two dictionaries side by side

- [`zip(*iterables)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
    for i, v1, v2 in enumerate(zip(kelime_sayi.most_common(), sorted(kelime_sayi.items()), 1):
        print('{}    {} {}'.format(i, v1, v2))
```